# Remove duplicated and count value in the same cell of a da

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I had a sample Dataframe with column a containing the duplicated values like below:

```
        a
0   1089, 1089, 1089
1   10A3, 10A3
2   10A3, 10A4, 10A4
3   TEL, TV
4   EZ, EZ
5   ABC Co., ABC Co.
```

I would like to remove the duplicates and count the value of each cell:

```
      a               count
0   1089                1
1   10A3                1
2   10A3, 10A4          2
3   TEL, TV             2
4   EZ                  1
5   ABC Co.             1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
def f(x):

    l = x.split(',')

    d = {}

    for key in l:
        if key.rstrip() not in d:
            d[key.rstrip()] = 0
        d[key.rstrip()]+=1

    return ','.join(list(d.keys()))
df['a_new'] = df['a'].apply(lambda x:f(x))
print(df)
df['count'] = df['a_new'].apply(lambda x: len(x.split(',')))
```

Comment: Thanks for input, but seems the duplicated value are not removed.

Comment: I created a new column, so you could delete the older one using df.drop(['a'],axis=1)

Comment: Happy to help!!

Answer (score 4):

Use [`str.get_dummies`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.get_dummies.html) and sum across `axis=1`

```
df['count'] = df.a.str.get_dummies(sep=', ').sum(1)
```

To remove the duplicates, use `explode`

```
s = df.assign(a=df.a.str.split(', ')).explode('a').drop_duplicates()
```

---

```
         a  count
0     1089      1
1     10A3      1
2     10A3      2
2     10A4      2
3      TEL      2
3       TV      2
4       EZ      1
5  ABC Co.      1
```

If you really need it all in the same line...

```
s.groupby(s.index).agg({'a': ', '.join, 'count': 'first'})

          a  count
0        1089      1
1        10A3      1
2  10A3, 10A4      2
3     TEL, TV      2
4          EZ      1
5     ABC Co.      1
```

---

Or simply use @WeNYoBen ingenious solution ;)

```
s=df.a.str.get_dummies(sep=', ')
df['a']=s.dot(s.columns+',').str[:-1]
df['count']=s.sum(1)
```

Comment: I got an error: AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'explode'

Comment: @JennyJingYu that;s only available on pandas version `0.25` onwards!

Answer (score 2):

You need to define your own method and apply it on your dataframe.

```
def list_count(x):
    l=pd.Series(x.split(',')).str.strip().drop_duplicates().tolist()
    return pd.Series([', '.join(l), len(l)])

df['a'].apply(lambda x: list_count(x)).rename(columns={0:'a', 1:'count'})
```

Output:

```
            a  count
0        1089      1
1        10A3      1
2  10A3, 10A4      2
3     TEL, TV      2
4          EZ      1
5     ABC Co.      1
```

Comment: thanks for your method, i works in the sample dataset, but it's very slow when applying to the large dataset.